# Why is table of contents page shifted in latex (Overleaf)

Tags: latex

I am using this template https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis. The second page of table of contents (and the first chapter) as shown in the figure.

[image: the second page is shifted to write]

Can anyone explain why this happens and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Margins are asymmetric for even/odd pages to bind them in a book

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The second page of "Table of contents" is shifted to the right instead of being aligned with the first page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overleaf is not responsible. Keep in mind the first comment above by @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz:

> Margins are asymmetric for even/odd pages to bind them in a book

This is enough of an explaination. But I downloaded the main tex file from your template: see (also thanks to the code highlighting below) the options available for your `documentclass`, each one in a new dedicated line and most of them commented. See the third line of the code that follows, notice that your template is set on `twoside` by default, but they give you the option to uncomment `oneside`.

```latex
\documentclass[
11pt, % The default document font size, options: 10pt, 11pt, 12pt
%oneside, % Two side (alternating margins) for binding by default, uncomment to switch to one side
english, % ngerman for German
singlespacing, % Single line spacing, alternatives: onehalfspacing or doublespacing
%draft, % Uncomment to enable draft mode (no pictures, no links, overfull hboxes indicated)
%nolistspacing, % If the document is onehalfspacing or doublespacing, uncomment this to set spacing in lists to single
%liststotoc, % Uncomment to add the list of figures/tables/etc to the table of contents
%toctotoc, % Uncomment to add the main table of contents to the table of contents
%parskip, % Uncomment to add space between paragraphs
%nohyperref, % Uncomment to not load the hyperref package
headsepline, % Uncomment to get a line under the header
%chapterinoneline, % Uncomment to place the chapter title next to the number on one line
%consistentlayout, % Uncomment to change the layout of the declaration, abstract and acknowledgements pages to match the default layout
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure
```

If `oneside` may be suitable for a pdf to be only uploaded online or for one-side printout, sure `twoside` is the one to choose for two-side book-like printout.

By the way, I studied in Southampton too but at Solent Uni `:)`